# Gradle JavaDoc hangs forever

Tags: java, gradle

I am using followings for build env.

Java: JDK 7 
Gradle: 4.1 (Wrapper) 
Build command: `./gradlew clean build --debug`

Gradle config:

```
task javadocs(type: Javadoc, dependsOn: compileJava) {
    source = sourceSets.main.allSource
    options.memberLevel = JavadocMemberLevel.PUBLIC
    classpath = configurations.compile
    // Some files I want to exclude
    excludes = ['**/A.vm', '**/B.vm', '**/C.vm', '**/D.vm']
}

task javadocJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: javadocs) {
    classifier = 'javadoc'
    from javadoc.destinationDir
}
```

Console output is attached here: [Console Output](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1X18I2s_urA3qiRk8zGnxCCJ4otPw-fLv)

This is the last output. It hangs there forever. I had to force kill the process. No extra log, nothing.

Can someone help me understand what is going on? Am I doing anything wrong in the config?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use following:

```
task javadocJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: javadoc){
    classifier='javadoc'
    from javadoc.destinationDir
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As part of our project build, we generate few classes on the fly (using Velocity template). These generate classes are huge (we are trying to find an alternate solution for this) and Javadoc task was hanging on them forever. We removed these classes from JavaDoc task's `source` path and the build was quick (as expected).

It seems JavaDoc task takes a lot of time scanning these long classes and was hanging forever.